# Is it possible to read constants from external contracts in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, constant

Say you have a contract defined like this:

```
pragam solidity >=0.8.0;

contract Foo {
    uint256 public constant MY_CONSTANT = 6174;
}
```

If I just import `Foo` in another contract, without inheriting from it, can I read `MY_CONSTANT`?

I tried doing it like this, but it didn't work.

```
pragam solidity >=0.8.0;

import { Foo } from "/path/to/Foo.sol";

contract Bar {
    function myFunction() external {
        uint256 myConstant = Foo.MY_CONSTANT; 
    }
}
```

I got the following error:

> TypeError: Member "MY_CONSTANT" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract SablierV2Pro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I just import Foo in another contract, without inheriting from it,
> can I read MY_CONSTANT ?

Without forcing a call, no. constant variables are hardcoded into the bytecode, they are not variables, don't take any storage, and don't make it to the ABI unless if you specify it as `public` but issuing a call to read a constant variable through the auto generated getter just doesn't make any sense...

If both `Foo` and `Bar` need that constant, but inheritance doesn't make sense for some reasons, I'd argue that the constant definition doesn't belong in `Foo` to begin with. In that case, it has the characteristics of a global / application-wide constant.

Solidity leaves the possibility of [declaring constant at a file level](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html#constant-and-immutable-state-variables) for those cases ([this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1290) might also be of interest). Assuming that the following code is placed in a file called `constants.sol` which holds various global constants for your application, including `MY_CONSTANT` :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

uint256 constant MY_CONSTANT = 6174;
// other global constants...
```

You can then import it and use it in both `Foo` and `Bar` :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./constants.sol";

contract Foo {
    // Doesn't need to declare MY_CONSTANT as this is done
    // at the file level in constants.sol

    // Use the imported definition from ./constants.sol
    function myFunction() external pure returns (uint256) {
        return MY_CONSTANT; 
    }
}

contract Bar {

    // Use the imported definition from ./constants.sol
    function myFunction() external pure returns (uint256) {
        return MY_CONSTANT; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for old solc version is to create a base contract with the constants and inherit it contracts in the contracts that need them.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0;

contract Constants {
    uint256 public constant MY_CONSTANT = 6174;
}

contract Foo is Constants {
    function foo() pure public returns (uint256) {
        return MY_CONSTANT;
    }
}

contract Bar is Constants {
    function bar() pure public returns (uint256) {
        return MY_CONSTANT;
    }
}
```

It won't work for libraries, so having global constants is the better solution.